# Controlling choices for reactive selectinput with other Selectinput

Tags: r, input, shiny, leaflet, reactive

I have two select inputs in my shiny app and I am trying to make it so that the first selectinput controls the dataset for both the leaflet map and for the other select input. When the "time" selectinput is "Day", I want the choices for the "food" selectinput to be dfmorn$food and I want the map to reflect this change. Likewise for "Night", I want the "food" input to display dfnight$food, and the map to reflect. Currently neither the map, nor the "food" selectinput are reacting to the "food" selectinput.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

#Data Sample

longN <- c(-96.72363, -96.72880, -96.72700)
latN <- c(17.06167, 17.06200, 17.06170 )
nameN <- c("jim", "grant", "pablo")
foodN <- c("tacos", "burger", "elote")


dfnight <- data.frame(longN, latN, nameN, foodN)

longM <- c(-96.7261564, -96.7260505, -96.7259757)
latM <- c(17.0543072,17.0548387, 17.0553262)
nameM <- c("bob", "frank", "sue")
foodM <- c("memelas","tortas", "tacos")

dfmorn <- data.frame(longM, latM, nameM, foodM)
#icons

puestocolorsN = c ("tacos" = 'green',
                  "burger" = 'orange',
                  "elote" = 'red'
                  )

colorsN = puestocolorsN[dfnight$food]

iconsN <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'ios-close',
                      iconColor = 'black',
                      library = 'ion',
                      markerColor = unname(colors) )
puestocolorsM = c ("tacos" = 'green',
                   "memelas" = 'orange',
                   "tortas" = 'black')

colorsM = puestocolorsM[dfmorn$food]

iconsM <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'ios-close',
                       iconColor = 'black',
                       library = 'ion',
                       markerColor = unname(colorsM)  )

#ui 


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Street Food Oaxaca"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "time",
        label = "Select Time",
        choices = c("Day", "Night"),
        selected = "Day"
      ),
      # uiOutput("conditionalUI")
      selectInput(
        inputId = "food",
        label = "Type of Food",
        choices = unique(dfmorn$food),
        selected = dfmorn$food[1:5],
        multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(h3("Map"), leafletOutput("map", width = "800", height = "600"))))

#server
server <- function(input, output, session){ 
  
  
  observeEvent(input$time, {
    
    reactive(
      if(input$time == "Day") {
        renderUI({
          SelectInput(
            inputId = "food",
            label = "Type of Food",
            choices = unique(dfmorn$food),
            selected = dfmorn$food[1:5],
            multiple = TRUE
          )
        })
      }else {
        renderUI({
          updateSelectInput(
            inputId = "food",
            label = "Type of Food",
            choices = unique(dfnight$food),
            multiple = TRUE
          )
          
        })
      } 
    )
  })
  dfmorn1 <- eventReactive(input$food, {
    dfmorn %>% dplyr::filter(food %in% input$food)
  })
  dfnight1 <- eventReactive(input$food, {
    dfnight %>% dplyr::filter(food %in% input$food)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$time, {
    
    reactive(
      if(input$time == "Day") {
        output$map = renderLeaflet({
          leaflet(data = dfmorn1()) %>%
            setView(lng = -96.725, lat = 17.0618, zoom =14)%>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addAwesomeMarkers(
              lng = ~long,
              lat = ~lat,
              icon = icons,
              label = ~as.character(dfmorn$name))
        })
      }else {
        output$map = renderLeaflet({
          leaflet(data = dfnight1()) %>%
            setView(lng = -96.725, lat = 17.0618, zoom =14)%>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addAwesomeMarkers(
              lng = ~long,
              lat = ~lat,
              icon = icons,
              label = ~as.character(dfmorn$name)
          )
          
        })
      } 
    )
  })

      }
  

 #Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Also still trying to figure out grouping the marker colors based on dfmorn$food and dfnight$food as discussed here: [Assigning color to leaflet awesomemarkers based on chr column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72410372/assigning-color-to-leaflet-awesomemarkers-based-on-chr-column)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few typos and incorrect way to update selectInput.  Try this

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

#Data Sample

longN <- c(-96.72363, -96.72880, -96.72700)
latN <- c(17.06167, 17.06200, 17.06170 )
nameN <- c("jim", "grant", "pablo")
foodN <- c("tacos", "burger", "elote")


dfnight <- data.frame(long=longN, lat=latN, name = nameN, food=foodN)

longM <- c(-96.7261564, -96.7260505, -96.7259757)
latM <- c(17.0543072,17.0548387, 17.0553262)
nameM <- c("bob", "frank", "sue")
foodM <- c("memelas","tortas", "tacos")

dfmorn <- data.frame(long=longM, lat=latM, name = nameM, food=foodM)

puestocolorsN = c ("tacos" = 'green',
                   "burger" = 'orange',
                   "elote" = 'red'
)

colorsN = puestocolorsN[dfnight$food]

iconsN <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'ios-close',
                       iconColor = 'black',
                       library = 'ion',
                       markerColor = unname(colorsN) )
puestocolorsM = c ("tacos" = 'green',
                   "memelas" = 'orange',
                   "tortas" = 'black')

colorsM = puestocolorsM[dfmorn$food]

iconsM <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'ios-close',
                       iconColor = 'black',
                       library = 'ion',
                       markerColor = unname(colorsM)  )

#ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Street Food Oaxaca"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "time",
        label = "Select Time",
        choices = c("Day", "Night"),
        selected = "Day"
      ),
      # uiOutput("conditionalUI")
      selectInput(
        inputId = "food",
        label = "Type of Food",
        choices = unique(dfmorn$food),
        selected = dfmorn$food[1:5],
        multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(h3("Map"), leafletOutput("map", width = "800", height = "600")))
)

#server
server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$time, {

    if(input$time == "Day") choices <- unique(dfmorn$food)
    else choices <- unique(dfnight$food)

      updateSelectInput(
        inputId = "food",
        label = "Type of Food",
        choices = choices,
        select=choices[1:3]
      )
  })

  dfmrn <- eventReactive(input$food, {
    if(input$time == "Day") df <- dfmorn
    else df <- dfnight
    df %>% dplyr::filter(food %in% input$food)
  })

  observe({print(dfmrn())})

  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    req(dfmrn())
    leaflet(data = dfmrn()) %>%
      setView(lng = -96.725, lat = 17.0618, zoom =14)%>%
      addTiles()
  })

  observeEvent(input$food, {
    if(input$time == "Day") icons <- iconsM
    else icons <- iconsN
    popup <- paste( "<b>Name:</b>", dfmrn()$name,  "<br>",  "<b>Type of food:</b>", dfmrn()$food)
    leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(
        data = dfmrn(),
        lng = ~long,
        lat = ~lat,
        icon = icons, popup = popup,
        label = ~as.character(name)
      )
  })

}

#Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @YBS for your quick response and your help. The code works exactly as I envisioned. I am having trouble adding a popup to addAwesomeMarkers()  that functions with both day and night. Works great for day, but crashes the app when input$time = "night". 
`addAwesomeMarkers( 
        data = dfmrn(),
        lng = ~long,
        lat = ~lat,
        icon = icons,
        popup = ~paste(
"<b>Name:</b>", name,
 "<br>",
 "<b>Type of food:</b>", food),
label = ~as.character(name)
      )`

Comment: popup works fine for me.  Please try the updated code.